# SharePoint Permissions - Access for everyone?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

We are currently migrating our intranet to a SharePoint based intranet. What we would like to do is add a URL into the older intranet linking to the new SharePoint so users across multiple departments can access and test the site before we go into production.

Is there any way for everyone based in our organization to view this site without having to accept manual permissions for every single user? We are using SharePoint Online.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

There is literally an "Everyone" principal in SharePoint Online that you can share your sites with. There is also "Everyone except External Users" which would exclude external users.[image]

**Important**: uncheck the "send mail" checkbox before clicking Share or you will end up spamming the entire org.

Comment: Thank you for the response. One thing I'd like to clarify is, when I add the "Everyone except external users" group to "Site Visitors", it automatically assigns that group to "Site Members" too. I want to give everyone in my org access to read and view content, but not create edits.                                                                                                        I've gone to advanced permission settings and added the permission there but it still reflects in both groups when I view "site permissions". Is there a way just to have it in "Site Visitors"?

Comment: See the little drop down under the word "Read"? That allows you to select Read, Contribute, or Full Control, which puts the recipients in the appropriate group.